# Compare User Input to AD Group for login

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, active-directory, ldap

I have a simple login page that takes a Username and a password and but I'm not sure how to take those values and compare them to an AD Group to allow only members of that group to login.

aspx

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
                <td align="Right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="ID: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="Right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
<table>
```

aspx.cs

```
        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (/* valid Username and Password */)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("PAGE.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblInvalid.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to allow only members of that group to access your login page. Look up <authorization> section of web.config

Comment: @Vasya Will that allow me to make use of the login page? I would like to have the users enter their info in the text boxes and have that be compared to the AD Group.

Comment: Look at the `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespaces for methods dealing with user info retrieval from AD and users' group memberships.

Comment: If this is an intranet application, look into using Windows Authentication so users don't need to type in their credentials at all.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci Does would that still only allow those within the correct AD group to enter the website?

Comment: Yes, you can configure it like that.